# How to display RTF in TypeScript?

Tags: html, typescript, richtextbox

I get the following string from a service and I simply want to display it in a textarea on my page:

```
<html><Font FontSize=\"17\" FontFamily=\"Arial\" ><Font FontSize=\"17\" FontFamily=\"Arial\" >Test</Font> </Font> <br /> </html>
```

If I set it this way to my textarea it just appears as it is, without any formatting.

```
var agenda_id = $("#agenda_text");
var agendaArea: JQuery = $('<textarea>');
agenda_id.append(agendaArea);
agendaArea.text(appointment.HtmlDescription);
```

[image]

I want to display the text 'Test' in the defined format.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Browsers don't support RTF editing in a textarea. You can convert it to HTML and use a WYSIWYG editor like TinyMCE.

Comment: Yes, but I need this for TypeScript. That is written in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you will need an RTF to HTML converter. I couldn't find one written in JavaScript. There are plenty of these in C# e.g http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2006/10/20/rtf_5f00_html.aspx

Comment: This one might work, but I didn't try it: https://code.google.com/p/obremsdk/source/browse/trunk/js/rtf2html.js

Answer (score 0):

Simplistically speaking, you have some (quite nasty) HTML that you want to show...

You can add it to an element (although beware of HTML injection attacks if the HTML is coming form an untrusted source, such as an end user).

```
var content = '<html><Font FontSize=\"17\" FontFamily=\"Arial\" ><Font FontSize=\"17\" FontFamily=\"Arial\" >Test <b>Test</b></Font> </Font> <br /> </html>';

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = content;

document.body.appendChild(div);
```

If you were adding it to a text box because you wanted to edit the text, you can add:

```
div.contentEditable = 'true';
```

But you are then responsible for marshalling the content in and out of the container and all of the accessibility that a standard form element would provide.